# Convert a column of database to a query for SQL

Tags: sql, r

I have a dataframe say

```r
var1<-data.frame(1:100)
```

I want to put this inside an SQL query for which I need this to be in the following form, in a variable say var2 which looks like this and is a character:

```r
"'1','2','3', .....'100'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try -

```
var1 <- data.frame(col = 1:100)
var2 <- toString(sprintf("'%d'", var1$col))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `paste`:

```
x <- c(1:100)
paste0("'", x, "'", collapse=",")

[1] "'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `sQuote` from `base R`

```
toString(sQuote(x, FALSE))
```

#### data

```
x <- 1:100
```